# trying to start site with docker, gunicorn, nginx, docker, uwsgi, and django but it will not start up

Tags: django, docker, nginx, gunicorn, uwsgi

I've read everywhere about getting the site running that I can possibly search for. However, I cannot get the site to run, I either get a 403 error or a 502 error (depending on the configuration). This is all installed inside of a docker container.

Currently what I'm trying to do is run uwsgi from command line and gunicorn from command line (to make sure my ini files are configured properly). I'm not getting any errors from command line now, but the site still will not load. Can anyone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
uwsgi --close-on-exec -s unix:///run/uwsgi/django/socket --chdir /var/www/html/mysite/ --pp .. -w blog.wsgi -C666 -p 32 -H /virtualenvpython3/ --uid www-data -gid www-data

/virtualenvpython3/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock mysite.wsgi:application
```

My nginx is file is configured like so (in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/blog):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.blog;
    location /assets {
        autoindex on;
        alias /var/www/html/mysite/assets;
        }
    location / {
        autoindex on;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///run/uwsgi/django/socket;
        include /var/www/html/mysite/mysite/uwsgi_params;
        }
}
```

Please let me know if you require any other information. Here is a sample from my error logs (nginx/error.log)

```
2022/01/07 07:17:34 [crit] 34#34: *17 connect() to unix:///run/uwsgi/django/socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 154.21.22.142, server: my.blog, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///run/uwsgi/django/socket:", host: "my.blog"
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and precise how docker is involved in that issue? Else please remove the tag. Thanks.

Comment: @Zeitounator sorry I forgot to include why I used the docker tag. I edited my original post but wanted to let you know that I included this because it is all inside of a docker container. I thought that might be relevant for some networking issues, but not all.